# Selenium/Protractor: ng-model locator and entering text

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am entering text into text fields, located by angular locators, using selenium and protractor.

However upon entering text, the field does not show text inside the field, until I click on it again i.e. it is not dynamically refreshing.

I use the below code to enter the text:

```
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerText = '" + text + "';", item);  
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = '" + text + "';", item);
```

The locator uses protractor referencing ng-model to locate the element.

How can I enter text and refresh the field so it displays the entered text. 
I have tried clicking on the field using selenium, but this does not work.

Many Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use element.sendKeys() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `element.sendKeys()` method.